# What are the purpose of having suspend keyword on Room Dao's function besides enforcing it to launch as coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

We can choose to have or not to have `suspend` keyword, for Room Dao function.

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Update
    suspend fun updateUsers(vararg users: User)
}


@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Update
    fun updateUsers(vararg users: User)
}
```

By using either way, we can still execute it within Coroutine launch.

```
val singleThreadDispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

lifecycleScope.launch(singleThreadDispatcher) {
    userDao.updateUsers(....
}
```

If that is so, what is the true purpose of having `suspend` keyword for Room Dao's function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-suspend function:

- Waits by **blocking**.
- Whenever we wait for something, we make the thread go to sleep. Thread can't do anything else while waiting, it is occupied by our function all the time.
- Non-suspend function cannot suspend.

Suspend function:

- Waits by **suspending**.
- Whenever we wait for something, the thread is free to do something else, for example run another coroutine.
- Suspend function is technically capable to block/sleep, but it should almost never do this. That causes coroutines to be unresponsive (exception: `Dispatchers.IO`)

These are general rules, they don't apply to Room only.

If we don't use coroutines in our application, we have no choice - we have to use non-suspend function as we won't be able to easily execute a `suspend` function.

If we use coroutines, a `suspend` function is more coroutine-friendly. `suspend` function "says" it will use coroutines/threads in an optimal way. We can potentially use a non-suspend function then execute it from a coroutine by using `Dispatchers.IO`, but a suspend function could use resources in a more optimal way.

By switching between non-suspend and suspend functions in Room, we make it choose an entirely different implementation. One of them waits by blocking, another waits by suspending, so allows the thread to go somewhere else.

By the way, in your specific example using a non-suspend function is simply wrong. As explained above, non-suspend functions wait by blocking and `lifecycleScope` uses the main thread, so this code actually blocks the UI.

Comment: Sorry. There is mistake in my code sample. It should use single thread. I fix that. If that is such a case, does suspend vs non-suspend still hold any differences as far as Room Dao function is concerned? Both outcome seems to be the same (Not blocking main app UI)

Comment: Effect is still pretty similar. If you use a non-suspend function, it will entirely block this single-threaded dispatcher, so it could only execute a single query at a time. If you use a suspend function, you should be able to handle multiple concurrent queries with just a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another aspect to this discussion. By adding the suspend keyword you effectively make the query cancelable. That is, if your code requires the query to be executed you have two choices:

1. define query in DAO without suspend keyword
2. wrap the suspendable query code into a withContext(NonCancellable) block

Imagine a function which does some important calculation and needs to store the result in the database afterwards. In this case you probably don't want the database call to be cancelable as you might lose information about the result if it is not persisted.